# Are there tugnuts made to fit forward facing horizontal dropouts on a Pashely Parabike?

Tags: dropouts, chain-tug

Are there tugnuts to fit forward facing horizontal dropouts for a Pashley Parabike?  Internal gear hub.

Comment: I found that tug nuts would fix the symptom but not the cause.  For me, reshaping the teeth in the axle nuts helped a lot, as did texturing the outer edge of the dropout which had work-hardened over the years.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. If the proposed duplicate doesn't address your issue, just edit your question to explain how your situation is different and it will automatically be flagged for reopening.